# BIRT Combo Box dynamic default value

Tags: parameters, combobox, scripting, birt

I have a BIRT combo box backed by a dataset with a dynamic query, defined in its beforeOpen script.

What I want to do next is to set the last value from the dataset as the default value in the combo box.

For example, if my dataset returns the values [1, 2, 3] then I want the combo box to have the value 3 preselected.

I guess I need to add logic in the getDefaultValueList script of the parameter, but I don't know how to get the value list programmatically. Id'd like to achieve something like the following:

```
var values = this.getValueList(); // This is the part I'm missing
var defaultValues = [];
defaultValues[0] = values[values.length - 1];
```

Thanks in advance,

Fran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know, default value expressions of parameters are evaluated before datasets, therefore i don't believe we can do this through a BIRT script.

Though with a small client-side javascript you could achieve the same. For example using jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#YourParameterName_selection  option:last-child').attr('selected', 'selected');
});
```

This script should be triggered in parameter jsp of your birt viewer.

Please note if you would need to run the report automatically with the last option of the parameter when nothing has been selected, it would be possible. But if i correctly understood this is not the requirement, you just want the item to be selected by default in the combo.